# Salesforce- Creating contact and user by importing CSV file & send notification email to User

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I want to create the contact & user related to account by importing csv file.After creating user, generated username & password should be send to the respective user's email address.

I am planning to use Vf page for accepting the csv file & the **Contact** & **User** API for adding contacts & Users. But I am not sure regarding the email notification to user through API.

So can anyone please provide me the best solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use `Database.insert()` flavor instead of straightforward `insert users;`

Check out the [DML options help topic](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database_dmloptions.htm#emailheader), especially the "emailHeader" property

Something like this should do the trick:

```
List<User> users = new List<User>(); // fill in with data from your CSV
Database.DMLOptions dlo = new Database.DMLOptions();
dlo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true;
database.insert(users, dlo);
```

Be aware though that you can't insert an inactive user. You can deactivate them straight after the insert but then they can't login so you'll probably want to suppress the sending of email, not enforce it. Make sure you have sufficient amount of licenses before you start!

Last but not least - you can cheat by setting the same password for them with `System.setPassword('user id', 'new password')` :) It's not recommended to expose this functionality to your end users though, can process only 1 user at a time and wastes 1 DML statement...